# Why Long Term Fuel Trims Remains in Negative?

Tags: engine, fuel-consumption, electronic-control-module

Dear Experts here im attaching log of 1SZ-FE, 1.0L engine for your kind consideration, please advice why my LTFT remains in -ive though MAF, Intake Air Temp sensor, ECT sensor and O2 sensor is working fine, also i had a compression test which is 170psi for each cylinder.

Request for your valuable comments and suggestions please.

[image: 1SZ-Fe LTFT Log]

[image]

Comment: If it's negative, the computer believes that you're running a little rich. That could be due to a leaking injector (too much fuel) or air delivery (not enough air). But, I'd probably not worry too much about a 3% offset on LTFT. If your STFTs are *very* negative, it might be a real problem.

Comment: Also, is it really 52º C where you are? That's insane.

Comment: Im from Pakistan, in my place now a days lowest temp is around 8 degree Celsius.